# Read a Registry Key

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, registry, dllimport

I have a web application which is importing DLLs from the bin folder.

```
const string dllpath = "Utility.dll";

    [DllImport(dllpath)]
```

Now what I want to do is first import the DLLs from a folder not in the current project but at some different location.

The path of that folder is stored in a registry key.

How should I do this?

**Edit**:

Why can't I work this out???

```
public partial class Reports1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\xyz");
    string pathName = (string)registryKey.GetValue("BinDir");

    const string dllpath = pathName;
    [DllImport(dllpath)]
    public static extern bool GetErrorString(uint lookupCode, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder buf, uint bufSize);

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
```

`string pathName = (string)registryKey.GetValue("BinDir");` is not working here, but is working in the pageload event...

But if I do this DLL import won't work...
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Reading the registry is pretty straightforward.  The `Microsoft.Win32` namespace has a `Registry` static class.  To read a key from the `HKLM` node, the code is:

```
RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\NodeName")
```

If the node is `HKCU`, you can replace `LocalMachine` with `CurrentUser`.

Once you have the `RegistryKey` object, use `GetValue` to get the value from the registry.  Continuing Using the example above, getting the pathName registry value would be:

```
string pathName = (string) registryKey.GetValue("pathName");
```

And don't forget to close the `RegistryKey` object when you are done with it (or put the statement to get the value into a `Using` block).

**Updates**

I see a couple of things.  First, I would change pathName to be a static property defined as:

```
Private static string PathName
{ 
    get
    {
         using (RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Copium"))
         {
              return (string)registryKey.GetValue("BinDir");
         }
    }
}
```

The two issues were:

1. The `RegistryKey` reference will keep the registry open.  Using that as a static variable in the class will cause issues on the computer.
2. Registry path's use forward slashes, not back slashes.

Answer (score 9):

None of these answers worked for me.  This is what I used:

```
static void Main()
{
    const string dotNetFourPath = "Software\\Microsoft";//note backslash
    using (RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(dotNetFourPath))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(registryKey.SubKeyCount);//registry is not null
        foreach (var VARIABLE in registryKey.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(VARIABLE);//here I can see I have many keys
            //no need to switch to x64 as suggested on other posts
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

All these answers may lead to problems running on 64bit OS - which is usual nowadays.

In my situation, i compile to 'Any CPU' target and the software is working fine when i install on 64bit OS.
But my unit tests are running into problems - obviously they are executed in 32bit mode.

In this case not the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyCompany\MySoftware` is searched but `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\MyCompany\MySoftware` but there are no entries!

In this situation we have to specify the start point of our search using

```
RegistryKey hklm = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64)
```

In total we can use.

```
string configurationDirectory = string.Empty;

using (RegistryKey hklm = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64))
{
    using (RegistryKey registryKey = hklm.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\MyCompany\MySoftware"))
    {
        if (registryKey != null)
        {
            configurationDirectory = (string)registryKey.GetValue("ConfigurationDirectory");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
try
{
    RegistryKey regKey = Registry.LocalMachine;
    regKey = regKey.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Application\");

    if (regKey != null)
    {
        return regKey.GetValue("KEY NAME").ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
/// <summary>
/// To read a registry key.
/// input: KeyName (string)
/// output: value (string) 
/// </summary>
public string Read(string KeyName)
{
    // Opening the registry key
    RegistryKey rk = baseRegistryKey ;
    // Open a subKey as read-only
    RegistryKey sk1 = rk.OpenSubKey(subKey);
    // If the RegistrySubKey doesn't exist -> (null)
    if ( sk1 == null )
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        try 
        {
            // If the RegistryKey exists I get its value
            // or null is returned.
            return (string)sk1.GetValue(KeyName.ToUpper());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // AAAAAAAAAAARGH, an error!
            ShowErrorMessage(e, "Reading registry " + KeyName.ToUpper());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

For more information visit [this web site](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C) .