# How to find whether office is installed

Tags: c#, .net, ms-office

How can I programatically find whether MS-office is installed on a machine, and if installed what components are installed,version and stuff like that.

How do I find whether it is office professional or office ultimate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can look in the Registry.

[According to the help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/orkXP/HA011364611033.aspx), it can be found in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\VERSION\Common\InstallRoot`.

The article also describes how to find specific product information, like components, type of release, etc.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675864/read-a-registry-key) explains how to read a key from the registry using C#, if you need help for this part.

Comment: @Wookai, thank you for your response I can find the version of the office that is installed but how do I find all the other details without using Windows Installer.

Answer (score 3):

In the Registry:

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\VERSION\Common\InstallRoot

Where VERSION is the version of Office you are looking for

Comment: @Nick, as of now I can only get the version of ms office installed how can I find what components are installed and all the other details