# How to read registry key values by specifying name in c#

Tags: c#, registry

I am writing a value into registry of my Windows.Now as per my requirement i have to read it without specifying the path name where it has been saved but i am not getting how to retrieve it.
Here is the code to write ..

```
        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey exampleRegistryKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("ExampleTest");
        exampleRegistryKey.SetValue("Conn", "Connection Test");
        exampleRegistryKey.Close();
```

Please help me how to read this key.
Thanks..

```
public static string PathName
{ 
get
{
    using (RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\ExampleTest"))
     {
         return (string)registryKey.GetValue("Conn");
     }
}
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Gets and sets normally come in pairs...

Comment: @eddie_cat Ok Can you please tell me from my code how i need to proceed?

Comment: Read this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675864/read-a-registry-key

Comment: @eddie_cat Please see my updated post with tried code as per your direction and tell me where i am wrong because i am not getting the values..

Comment: @eddie_cat R u there helping me..?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following method to get a value of registry key by its name:

```
   public static string PathName
     { 
      get
         {
          RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\ExampleTest")
          string registryContent = (Registry.GetValue(registryKey.Name, "Con", "not exist")).ToString();
          return registryContent;  
         }
     }
```

The text "not exist" will be returned in case the `Con` value was not found in the registry.